# How to get the equivalent of the accuracy in Google Map Geocoder V3

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-api

I want to get geocode from google, and I used to do it with the V2 of the API.
Google send in the json a pretty good information, the accuracy, reference here : http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GGeoAddressAccuracy

In V3, Google doesn't seem to send me exactly the same information. There is the array "adresse_component", which seem bigger if the accuracy is better, but not exactly.
For example, I have a request accuracy to the street number, the array is of size 8.
Another query is accuracy to the route, so less accuracy, but the array is still of size 8, as there is a row 'sublocality', which not appear in the first case.

Ok, for a result, Google send a data 'types', which have the 'best' accuracy. This types are here : http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types
But, there is no real order, and if I wan't the result better than postal_code, I have no clue to how to do that.

So, how can I get this equivalent of the V2 accuracy, whithout some dumb and horrible code ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, there is the [location type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), which is not so bad :

> location_type stores additional data about the specified location. The
> following values are currently supported:
>
> "ROOFTOP" indicates that the returned result is a precise geocode for which we have location information accurate down to street address precision.
>
> "RANGE_INTERPOLATED" indicates that the returned result reflects an
> approximation (usually on a road) interpolated between two precise
> points (such as intersections). Interpolated results are generally
> returned when rooftop geocodes are unavailable for a street address.
>
> "GEOMETRIC_CENTER" indicates that the returned result is the geometric
> center of a result such as a polyline (for example, a street) or
> polygon (region)."
>
> "APPROXIMATE" indicates that the returned result is
> approximate.

I test if the location_type is different of approximate, and it gives some good results.

Comment: FYI the numbers don't map directly. I've just come across an address that gives an accuracy of 6 with V2 and GEOMETRIC_CENTER with V3. Annoyingly maps itself can give a rooftop match.

Comment: I am getting a rooftop on a city. This seems strange

Answer (score 7):

With Google deprecating their Geocoding v2 API later this year, there's going to be a ton of people migrating their geocoding logic to v3 and this very question is going to crop up:  How to map the 'location_type' string to an equivalent 'accuracy'?

Here's a decent mapping:

```
"ROOFTOP" -> 9
[Everything else] -> 4 to 8 (aka the text string might as well read "GARBAGE")
```

If something other than ROOFTOP is specified, use the **area** of 'northeast' and 'southwest' to decide if it is accurate enough for you.

Now what should happen if you don't get something "accurate"?  Run a Google Places text search query for the same address.  Google Places does geocoding as well and, with Billing enabled, you can get 10,000 Places text search queries per day (no rate limit) and Google claims they won't charge the card (they supposedly just use it for verifying the account).  With Billing, you get 100,000 queries, but Places text search queries have a "cost" of 10 times the amount of a regular Places query, hence the aforementioned 10,000 limit.  Places can be finicky though and you should only consider responses with one result.

Sometimes Places queries will not return a zipcode - especially if one isn't sent.  If you need the zipcode, take the lat/lng results of the Places query and feed it back into the geocoder, which will usually spit out an address with a zipcode (and very frequently a ROOFTOP match).

It should be noted that the official Geocoding API courtesy limit is 2,500 requests per day with a rate limit of one per second per IP address.  Therefore, following the above formula will likely decimate and may even halve the number of geocodings available to you.

If you need more than the Google Geocoding limit (who doesn't?), invent your own mini geocoding service with something like the OpenStreetMap database.  Clone the parts of OpenStreetMap that you need and write your own geocoder (or use a library).  Then you can geocode to your heart's content with no quantity limit or rate limit.  If you still use Google Maps, you can use Google's geocoder as a fallback should the OSM geocoder not be accurate enough for all cases.

Alternatively, if you trust your users to not submit bogus data (really?) and have to use the Google geocoding service, you could also abuse a user's web browser by having the browser geocode information for you and then feed the results to your server.  You might burn through the user's daily limit and you risk someone pushing bogus data, but if you are going to all that trouble, do you actually care?

At any rate, the tips above should suffice for interim usage for most users to get a working v3 API set up.  Ran into this issue myself, so figured I'd share with the community a halfway decent solution.  I still think v2 was the better API - integer accuracy ratings instead of ugly text strings always wins out.

Comment: I'd like to add that ROOFTOP is also the response on a wide range of garbage. It will just point to a "random" location which Google found to be best match.

Answer (score 1):

Paula's answer is good but you do need to also consider John's comment that ROOFTOP can return garbage.

I use a post-geocode-query sanity checker to get rid of those cases where location_type is 'ROOFTOP' but the address has nothing to do with the address you sent to google - this sanity checker compares the new address with the old address and considers what changed and by how much. The google geocoder is good at fixing typos, sometimes, but it can also make some non-sensical decisions - for instance choose a different city, a different state, or a different country. You need to decide if the result is a fix in a typo or if the geocode logic went astray.

So, don't just assume ROOFTOP == 9. It can also be garbage if the new address is way off from the original that you sent.

For things like Apartments or building with multiple units, the location_type = 'RANGE_INTERPOLATED' *may* also be accurate when the result type is 'subpremise'.

Remember, geocoding is not the same thing as address validation. They have some overlap but google geocode logic tries too hard to get you an answer, even when your input is garbage.

Comment: Hi @TheRealZing - you mentioned that for `ROOFTOP` results you still compare the new address with the old address and considers what changed and by how much. How exactly do you do this sanity check? Some sort of fuzzy matching?

Comment: I use several methods including: (1) sending the corrected address to a real address validation site, (2) scoring the two addresses with various algorithms include Jaro-Winkler comparison, proximity of the two zipcodes, Levenshtein distance and looking for standard USPS abbreviations.